# OracleDataAdapter returns no rows, but the query string works in SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle, adapter

visual studion 2008
oracle db 11.1.0.7
oracle client for .NET

I have a relatively simple query, that selects the rows from across multiple tables (up to 4) using joins. OracleDataAdapter returns no rows for the only dataset's table, but if I copy and paste that query in SQLDeveloper then I get the desired results.
I can get the data from other tables using the adapter with no problem, but it seems like it struggles with the bit longer selection query (string length is ~ 300 (not that much at all))

Connection string for the connection is 100% correct.

Any ideas? thank you...

Comment: Although your question is ok, please answer to your own question separately and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

- Check that you using same oracle user to connect to database. Maybe FGAC hides data.
- Check that there is no temporary tables in you query.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

The problem was, that after I imported the data in the SQLDeveloper in one of the involved tables, this change hasn't been committed automatically as I've falsely presumed... I've figured this out after I edited some data in the same table within the SQLDeveloper, and it has failed with the message that the edit operation on uncommitted action is now allowed. The headache I had was in SQLDeveloper, not the DataAdapter.